# Java Swing Run program when Windows startup

Tags: java, windows, swing, startup

Is there possible to code the Java Swing application to run when Windows start up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a batch file which runs your program, save it in Start menu > Programs > Startup

for example in win XP this folder would be 
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup or 
C:\Documents and Settings[YOURUSERNAME]\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: This answer is incorrect. This runs the application when a user logs in, not when Windows starts.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun

http://www.nthelp.com/40/autorun.htm